# Removing/Adding wc_print_notices on cart page?

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

I’ve trying to move the woocomerce messages alert that appears on the cart page. i/e when you update the cart quantity etc.

I’ve tried the following..

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_print_notices' );
```

No luck.

I’ve tried removing..

```
wc_print_notices();
```

From line 23 of the cart.php

No luck.

Tried hooking into the cart collaterals hook and again no luck..

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'wc_print_notices',    15 );
```

Any ideas, seems you cannot do anything on that particular page, you can move around the wc_print_notices on other pages?

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing, and have tried all the options you list and many more. Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?